# ENDECA - Crawl returns error in baseline_update

Tags: cas, endeca, endeca-workbench

I'm facing an error when I ran the baseline_update.bat from the control folder, I tried to restar_services but it didn't help at all. It happen everytime that I want run the baseline..

> Error starting baseline crawl 'MediaSource'. Occurred while executing
>   line 8 of valid BeanShell script:  [[
>
> 5|    if (LockManager.acquireLock("update_lock")) {
>   6|
>
> 7|   // archive logs and run the crawl.
>   8|
>   CAS.runBaselineCasCrawl("MediaSource");
>   9|
>   10|      // clean directories
>
> 11|      Forge.cleanDirs();
>
> ]]
>
> Aug 24, 2019 10:39:44 PM com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller
>   execute SEVERE: Caught an exception while invoking method 'run' on
>   object 'BaselineUpdate'. Releasing locks.
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller.invokeRequestedMethod(Controller.java:933)
>     at
>   com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller.execute(Controller.java:271)
>     at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller.main(Controller.java:138)
>   Caused by:
>   com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.AppControlException: Error
>   executing valid BeanShell script.     at
>   com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script.runBeanShellScript(Script.java:180)
>     at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script.run(Script.java:127)
>     ... 7 more Caused by:
>   com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.CasCommunicationException:
>   Error starting baseline crawl 'MediaSource'.  at
>   com.endeca.eac.toolkit.component.cas.ContentAcquisitionServerComponent.startBaselineCasCrawl(ContentAcquisitionServerComponent.java:451)
>     at
>   com.endeca.eac.toolkit.component.cas.ContentAcquisitionServerComponent.runBaselineCasCrawl(ContentAcquisitionServerComponent.java:357)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)  at
>   bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Unknown Source)    at
>   bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)     at
>   bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(Unknown Source)  at
>   bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)     at
>   bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)     at
>   bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(Unknown Source)    at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(Unknown
>   Source)   at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(Unknown Source)    at
>   bsh.BSHIfStatement.eval(Unknown Source)   at
>   bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)  at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown
>   Source)   at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script.runBeanShellScript(Script.java:165)
>     ... 8 more Caused by: Cannot start the already running crawl
>   MediaSource   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)  at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.(BeanDeserializer.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.(BeanDeserializer.java:90)
>     at
>   com.endeca.cas.wsdl.CrawlInProgressFaultInfo.getDeserializer(CrawlInProgressFaultInfo.java:81)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.getSpecialized(BaseDeserializerFactory.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.getDeserializerAs(BaseDeserializerFactory.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.getDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:464)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.getDeserializerForType(DeserializationContext.java:547)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultDetailsBuilder.onStartChild(SOAPFaultDetailsBuilder.java:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:379)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
>     at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)    at
>   org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)     at
>   org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)    at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)  at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)    at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)    at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)    at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)    at
>   com.endeca.cas.wsdl.CasCrawlerServiceSoapBindingStub.startCrawl(CasCrawlerServiceSoapBindingStub.java:916)
>     at
>   com.endeca.eac.toolkit.component.cas.ContentAcquisitionServerComponent.startBaselineCasCrawl(ContentAcquisitionServerComponent.java:447)
>     ... 27 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe late but, try to run the following script:

```
$ ENDECA_DIR/Apps/$YOUR_APP_NAME/control/runcommand.sh LockManager releaseLock update_lock
```

Greetings!